# Draw horizontal lines from x=0 to data points in matplotlib scatterplot (horizontal stem plot)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

Consider the follwing plot:

[image]

produced by this function:

```
def timeDiffPlot(dataA, dataB, saveto=None, leg=None):
    labels = list(dataA["graph"])
    figure(figsize=screenMedium)
    ax = gca()
    ax.grid(True)
    xi = range(len(labels))
    rtsA = dataA["running"] / 1000.0 # running time in seconds
    rtsB = dataB["running"] / 1000.0 # running time in seconds
    rtsDiff = rtsB - rtsA
    ax.scatter(rtsDiff, xi, color='r', marker='^')
    ax.scatter
    ax.set_yticks(range(len(labels)))
    ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
    ax.set_xscale('log')
    plt.xlim(timeLimits)
    if leg:
        legend(leg)
    plt.draw()
    if saveto:
        plt.savefig(saveto, transparent=True, bbox_inches="tight")
```

What matters here is the positive or negative difference of the values to `x = 0`. It would be nice to visualize this more clearly, e.g.

- emphasize the x=0 axis
- draw a line from x=0 to the plot marker

Can this be done with matplotlib? What code would need to be added?

Comment: To draw a "line" from x=0 to the points, you should simply try making a bar chart, either instead of or superimposed on the existing one.

Comment: You have a log plot, i.e. the point x=0 cannot be shown.

Comment: You could use ax.vlines() or ax.axvline(), but indeed they wont show at x=0 on log.

Comment: @DavidZwicker Thanks for pointing that out. I need to modify my plot so that 0 can be shown.

Comment: @RutgerKassies: Good point. There are also the more direct `pyplot.vlines()` and `pyplot.hlines()`, which are applied to the current axes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out by Rutger Kassies, there are actually some "stem" functions that automate the "manual" method from my other answer. The function for horizontal stem lines is `hlines()` (`vlines()` is for vertical stem bars):

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot

x_arr = numpy.random.random(10)-0.5; y_arr = numpy.arange(10)

pyplot.hlines(y_arr, 0, x_arr, color='red')  # Stems
pyplot.plot(x_arr, y_arr, 'D')  # Stem ends
pyplot.plot([0, 0], [y_arr.min(), y_arr.max()], '--')  # Middle bar
```

The [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hlines) for `hlines()` is on the Matplotlib website.

[image: Plot with horizontal stem bars]

Comment: Modern matplotlib allows `stem(...., orientation='horizontal')`

Answer (score 2):

(See my other answer, for a faster solution.)

Matplotlib offers vertical "stem" bars: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.stem. However, I can't find a horizontal equivalent of `stem()`.

One can nonetheless draw horizontal stem bars quite easily, through repeated `plot()` calls (one for each stem).  Here is an example

```
import numpy
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot

x_arr = numpy.random.random(10)-0.5; y_arr = numpy.arange(10)

# Stems:
for (x, y) in zip(x_arr, y_arr):
    plot([0, x], [y, y], color='red')
# Stem ends:
plot(x_arr, y_arr, 'D')
# Middle bar:
plot([0, 0], [y_arr.min(), y_arr.max()], '--')
```

with the following result:

[image: Plot with horizontal stem bars]

Note, however, that drawing bars from x = 0 does not make sense when x is on a log scale, as David Zwicker pointed out, since x = 0 is infinitely far on the left of the x axis.