# How determine the time a customer will churn

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, model

I'm doing time based retention modal and i want to know the time in which customer churn.

My data consist of customer_id, tenure, recency, frequency and monetary and the maximum tenure = 90days.

Is the lifelines algorithm can show the time to churn?

what can I do here any suggestion please

I did this:

```
x_arr = data['tenure']
y_arr = data['customer_id']
z_arr = data['churn'] #I don't know how to insert this as legend, it have 0 to 1 values
plt.hlines(y_arr, 0, x_arr, color='red')
plt.plot(x_arr, y_arr, 'X') #line end
```

[image]

Note:
I want to add another churn column to act as a legend where the red line should be will show customer churn and the blue line to show customer retained.

The bottom title should be time in days
left title should be customer

the maximum time is 90 days

in short it should look like the following picture exactly

[image]

Comment: You can use survival analysis 


https://square.github.io/pysurvival/tutorials/churn.html


https://towardsdatascience.com/survival-analysis-in-python-a-model-for-customer-churn-e737c5242822

Comment: @Paladinic I saw the article but I can't see which algorithm where used for the plot first time based hand drawn plot can you tell me please look at the first plot with handdrawn

Comment: If you are asking how to reproduce the hand-drawn chart ( https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*yHhG4TVcAAi29Ln88t0_5Q.png ) then you could use something like this ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957567/draw-horizontal-lines-from-x-0-to-data-points-in-matplotlib-scatterplot-horizon )

Comment: If you are asking about the implementation of the whole article in code, she shares the notebook at the end.  (https://github.com/loldja/loldja.github.io/blob/master/assets/code/blog/Kaplan%20Meier%20demo.ipynb)

Comment: @Paladinic I'm sorry can you demonstrate the same example with lifelines graph, I want to see how to draw the customer against tenure with their behavior either they churn or not as shown on the hand drawn example above, I want some to show me exactly how to implement it, the link you provided doesn't give the same solution help me please